# Blazor web assembly website not working in Azure Static WebApp

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-static-web-app

I have an existing website in Blazor Web assembly and it is working fine with Azure store account (Azure Storage Static Website).

The same app, when I deployed in Azure Static WebApp through GitHub workflow action, is not working.

I can see below errors in the browser console window.

[image]

Only JavaScript files under `_content` and `_framework` folders are not able to load. I don't see any option in Azure Static WebApp to verify these files deployed successfully or not.

**Updated**

Visual Studio 2019 default template app with default GitHub workflow working but I cannot use default workflow file so I tried to change as per my folder structure, below is my project structure

- `Root/MyApp/MyApp.csproj`
- `Root/MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj`

Answer (score 1):

Azure Static Web Apps are currently in preview and support JavaScript and TypeScript front-end apps including those developed with popular frameworks like Vue.js, React, Angular and more.

Since it uses Github actions to deploy the application we just need to modify the workflow file generated by azure static web app to deploy our Blazor Application.

you can refer the article to deploy Blazor WASM app:
https://www.maneu.net/blog/2020-05-deploy-blazor-client-apps-with-azure-static-apps/

Comment: I agree it's in preview, Even I tried sample application and it was working. I will try above link and see if am missing anything..